# how to make text bold in a tikz style?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\tikzset{user/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.6cm, fill=Black, draw=none, text=White}}
```

How should I insert bold style in this?

Comment: See section "16.4.2 Text Parameters: Font" of the PGF manual.

Comment: Now it's section 17.4.2. (also if it doesn't need to be in the style conventional `\bf` / `\textbf` works in most cases as long as  you put the ``\\`` in top level)

Answer (score 32):

Add `font=\bfseries`:

```
\tikzset{user/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.6cm, fill=Black,
    draw=none, text=White, font=\bfseries}}
```

Comment: I am not getting any error, but the text doesnt seem to become bold, why?

Comment: @user494461 could it be a mistake in your drawing? Please show how you draw/place the node.

Comment: @user494461 You could edit your question to show a compilable minimum example, so we can see your other settings which may interfere.